# Cancelling Facebook Connect permissions of a site?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I wrongfully approved permission request of a site that demands almost all the possible permissions that could be granted via Facebook Connect.

Now I can't manage to cancel off these permissions. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open [Privacy Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy), click *Apps and Websites* at the bottom of Privacy, remove the website from "Apps you use".